# Visual studio breaks on circular reference, console application does not running the same python

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have a python method which uses code `foo = locals()` which leads to a circular reference. If I run the code from console, say using `python.exe run.py` the code works and runs till the end. If I however run the same code in Visual Studio, it breaks on ValueError: Circular reference detected. The Visual studio is using exactly the same python interpreter as I call in the console. How is this possible?

Edit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Projekty\Betfair\Repos\Betfair\run.py", line 16, in <module>
text_query='Horse Racing'
File "C:\Program Files\conda\lib\site-
packages\betfairlightweight\endpoints\betting.py", line 33, in 
list_event_types
response = self.request(method, params, session)
File "C:\Program Files\conda\lib\site-
packages\betfairlightweight\endpoints\baseendpoint.py", line 27, in request
request = self.create_req(method, params)
File "C:\Program Files\conda\lib\site-
packages\betfairlightweight\endpoints\baseendpoint.py", line 52, in 
create_req
return json.dumps(payload)
File "C:\Program Files\conda\lib\json\__init__.py", line 230, in dumps
return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
File "C:\Program Files\conda\lib\json\encoder.py", line 198, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "C:\Program Files\conda\lib\json\encoder.py", line 256, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
ValueError: Circular reference detected
```

Comment: Could you show the full stack trace, so we can see where the ValueError is coming from? I'm speculating that it's from some string representation of a value trying to convert something to JSON when the debugger tries to display it, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with running

```
foo = locals()
```

in a program, in either case. Circular references are very common, and shouldn't stop the program. However, it sounds like you're using a debugger which is trying to visualize the value `foo`, but can't support visualizing values with circular references. (It might be trying to convert the value to JSON.)

If your debugger can't handle circular references, look for an option to ignore `foo` in its inspector/watcher to avoid the crash.

Comment: That's also what I suspected, however I cannot find a way how to exclude that variable from the watch.